# SupperTab support list UltiSnips snippets

Tags: vimrc, plugin-ultisnips, plugin-supertab

I install the SperTab and UltiSnips plugins. I want to integrate SuperTab and UltiSnips but fail. Here is an example

```
snippet numpy "import numpy" bw
import numpy as np
endsnippet

snippet nu "something else" bw
# do something
endsnippet
```

However, when I do insert `nu` and press `<tab>`, it will insert `# do something`. I hope I have a list of previous define variables and the possible snippets for me to choose.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Sorry. I decide to delete it, since I can not reproduce it and didn't encounter the issue anymore.